# Suitable GLM function in R for skewed continuous percentage abundance data

Tags: r, generalized-linear-model

I have a small dataset, and I am checking the abundance of two components by calculating their percentage abundance. When I check the distribution of the continuous variables, they are mostly skewed towards zero and hundred. I wanted to ask which glm would be appropriate for such data.

hist(component1)

[image]

fitdistrplus::descdist(component1, boot=1000)

[image]

Can you please guide me how to perform the analysis.

Comment: Why are they so skewed? That is, what substantive reasons are there for almost every case to be 0 or 100?

Comment: @PeterFlom They are rare components, but have some importance for our study. For some samples, one of them detected only so either zero or 100% when we checked their ratios to each other

Comment: OK, two more questions: 1) Are these the dependent variable or an independent variable and 2) (Esp. if they are a DV) are you sure you want to model percentages?

Comment: @PeterFlom they are dependent. I can also try to calculate one ratio column. In my previous attempts, I tried to use minimum abundance other than zero as pseudo-number, divide the abundances and apply log transformation, but we wanted to test it first

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a rare case where I would consider dichtomizing the data to 0 and 100 and then using logistic regression.  Another possibility is to use Poisson or negative binomial regression on the count with an offset for what was the denominator.

The choice, I think, depends on substantive issues: Do you want the actual abundance or the proportion?

Comment: Thank you for your time and precious suggestions

Comment: You're welcome. If my answer fulfills your needs, you can accept it by clicking the green check mark. But if you want more answers, that's fine too.

Comment: I posted my comment as an answer to be able to include qqplot. Any comments are highly appreciated

Comment: I deleted my answer as the qqplot does not make any sense, sorry for my mistake. Thanks again for your help and guidance

Answer (score 3):

In that histogram you're examining the marginal distribution, which is not a useful strategy $-$ a GLM is a model for the *conditional* distribution which may be quite unlike the marginal (e.g. it may be that every conditional distribution is unimodal but the marginal is bimodal). This is a distressingly common error, perhaps one of the most common modelling errors of all. Calculations like the skewness and kurtosis (per your plot) will presumably also be of marginal distributions and so likely highly misleading.

If your abundances are based on *counts* perhaps the most obvious generalized linear model would relate to logistic regression (once you convert proportions back to counts so you don't screw up the relative variances), though you might run into issues of (semi-)complete separation. However, by the sound of it you may want a random effect in there (i.e. a GLMM instead), or perhaps some quasi binomial might suffice to model heterogeneity in a very basic way if that doesn't seem suitable.

If your abundances are some form of continuous variable (i.e. not originating from ratios of integers, for example), then I'd probably look  at 0-1 inflated beta regression (also likely with logit link). Again, possibly with a random effect, perhaps. However, again, issues of differing relative variances arising from different sample sizes might suggest using gamma GLMs for the raw abundances rather than scaling them to a fraction and losing the sample size information (though you could use a weighted beta regression to account for sample size).